# Setting a breakpoint, but breakpoint not hit

Tags: c++, gdb, chromium

I've built Chromium locally, and I'm trying to debug it with GDB. For some reason, certain breakpoints do not seem to hit. For example, when I do

```
b InjectedScriptBase::makeEvalCall
```

GDB prompts

```
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (InjectedScriptBase::makeEvalCall) pending.
```

but when the relevant code is triggered, the breakpoint is not hit.

What am I doing wrong? I'm currently assuming that the relevant symbols are loaded at run-time, but should I load them separately?

Comment: The symbols should be available at load-time already. Did you build with debug symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Chromium sources](http://src.chromium.org/multivm/trunk/webkit/Source/WebCore/inspector/InjectedScriptBase.cpp) this function has rather long signature:

```
void InjectedScriptBase::makeEvalCall(ErrorString* errorString, ScriptFunctionCall& function, RefPtr<TypeBuilder::Runtime::RemoteObject>* objectResult, TypeBuilder::OptOutput<bool>* wasThrown)
```

So it's worth to use Tab completition while setting breakpoint. Try the following:

```
b 'InjectedScriptBase::makeEvalCall
```

and push Tab key to autocomplete function name. gdb should lookup symbol table and autocomplete function name for you. Then you should be able to set breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks. Is the `'` intentional in `b '`?

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to add trailing `'`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough memory to debug Chromium. Or try to debug it on another machine with more memory.